# Can I install 10.04 after 12.04?

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (**32 bit**) on a laptop with Windows 7 (32 bit): the bootloader is the GRUB version provided with Ubuntu 12.04. Now I would also install Ubuntu 10.04 (**64 bit**), without overwriting the bootloader installed with Ubuntu 12.04. Obviously I would like the GRUB previously installed by Ubuntu 12.04 can boot all operating systems installed (Windows 7, Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 12.04).

- Could the bootloader installed by Ubuntu 12.04 (**32 bit**) start also Ubuntu 10.04 (**64 bit**)?
- If I install Ubuntu 10.04 unchecking the option to install GRUB, the previous version of GRUB should not GRUB would not be configured to start Ubuntu 10.04.
- What is the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Ubuntu 10.04 without installing GRUB, then boot 12.04, open a terminal and run this command:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

12.04's Grub2 will add 10.04 to list. It will boot both 32 and 64 bit versions of the kernel.

Comment: Great, it works! However, this command has created multiple duplicate entries "Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (10.04) (on /dev/sda7)".

Comment: You can edit boot entries with this command: gksudo /boot/grub/grub.cfg